# Python Scaffolder Versioning

Tags: python, scaffolding, cookiecutter

I've been working on core python app backend project, for which i've developed scaffolder project using cookiecutter library.

This scaffolder project is version controlled through github, if suppose few team members are using v1.0 scaffolder release for say project A and later point, if make change to scaffolder project and release it as 2.0, then for Project A again we need to retrofit the changes manually, Can any one please suggest is there better solution / alternative for this problem,

Looking for better solution approach